Select all shapes in Corel Draw that are in a specific rectangular area with an vba macro
Is there a way in Corel Draw to select only the shapes of a layer that are located in a certain rectangular area of a page with an Corel VBA Macro?
I found so long only a way to select all or by name, but nothing to select by range.
For Example: Select all shapes in an Rectangel form Postinen 1,1 to 500,200.

CorelDRAW supports a .FindShapes method that in turn takes a CQL search command.
CQL lets you describe the objects you want.
ActivePage.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@fill.color = cmyk(100,0,0,0)").CreateSelection

as an example, that finds all of the objects with a specific cmyk value (taken from this SO post.)
If you can describe the area of the page to CQL, this you should be able to somewhat efficiently find the objects in that area of the page.
CQL documentation is relatively sparse, and I am not an expert at it.
https://www.v-cut.com/files/public/Corel/CQL_Syntax.htm - this seems to be a reasonable description of the syntax.
There appears to be CenterX, Width, Height, Left, Right, Top, Bottom properties.  Given a (minX, minY), (maxX, maxY) values, maybe
Layer.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@left < " & maxX & " & @top < " & maxY & " & @right > " & minX & " & @bottom > " & maxY").CreateSelection

after debugging (I forget if Corel's VBA coordinates uses positive up or down, for example, and do you mean for the min/max to be inclusive or exclusive, and does that handle units right?) it should get you closer to what you are asking for.
